# How can i force gdb resolve plt addresses to names in disassembled output?

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, elf

I was given a [binary](https://files.buuoj.cn/files/7b4c75e815d450792be5eb85da0a2c09/ez_pz_hackover_2016?token=eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMjUwOCwidGVhbV9pZCI6bnVsbCwiZmlsZV9pZCI6Mjk1fQ.X3fZUA.chiHnqcLH6ZUOA4Vo_BqV47uMss). After it is loaded and launched using gdb, I found that in `disass` output the `call` instruction always display plt address instead of plt names. In the following example, the address `0x8048430` is displayed instead of its function name `printf()`.

```
(gdb) disas chall
Dump of assembler code for function chall:
   0x08048603 <+0>:     push   %ebp
   0x08048604 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048606 <+3>:     sub    $0x418,%esp
   0x0804860c <+9>:     sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x0804860f <+12>:    lea    -0x40c(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048615 <+18>:    push   %eax
   0x08048616 <+19>:    push   $0x8048818
   0x0804861b <+24>:    call   0x8048430
   0x08048620 <+29>:    add    $0x10,%esp
   0x08048623 <+32>:    sub    $0xc,%esp
   0x08048626 <+35>:    push   $0x8048830
   0x0804862b <+40>:    call   0x8048430 <========= PLT address
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q
Quit
(gdb) x/i 0x8048430
   0x8048430:   jmp    *0x8049fe4 <================ GOT address
(gdb)
```

The reason why `0x8048430` and `0x8049fe4` are claimed to be `printf()`, is revealed by the python code using pwntools

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
from pwn import *

filename = './ez_pz_hackover_2016'
e = ELF(filename)

log.level = 'DEBUG'
for k, v in e.got.items():
    log.debug(f'got:{k}={hex(v)}')
```

with the following output:

```
[DEBUG] got:setbuf=0x8049fdc
[DEBUG] got:strcmp=0x8049fe0 
[DEBUG] got:printf=0x8049fe4 <=====================
```

It is not very convenient to read such assembly in gdb `disass`. Is there any handy method to automatically convert plt addresses into names in gdb assembly?

Comment: Does your binary have debug symbols so `objdump -drwC -Mintel` resolves it to `printf@plt`?  (Or leave out the `-Mintel` if you prefer AT&T syntax.)

Comment: @PeterCordes It is weird. `objdump -drwC -Mintel` outputs `call 8048430 <_init+0x50>` instead of `printf@plt`

Comment: Ok, so I think pwntools is having to do more reverse-engineering for you, perhaps tracing into the PLT and finding which GOT entry it uses. GDB doesn't do that.  The target symbol name has to be there for dynamic linking, but the PLT entries themselves are just code and don't need symbols on those labels.  GDB is designed for debugging code you compiled with debug info (and works fine for that), not for reverse engineering.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. I found that IDA freeware has nice features on decompiling binary and i am going to use it instead.